# fmul st(0), qword ptr ss:[ebp-10] -> debugging in x64dbg

Tags: assembly, x64dbg

The x64dbg shows something different in the memory dump and something different in the results preview:

[x64dbg_screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5Lnt.png)

Correct value is 1 (as in preview), because result in ST(0) after this line stay the same. But I don't know from where is this 1 come from, because in 'Dump 1' and stack view I can see 000000000.
I have never had such problems with x64dbg before (x64dbg is in the newest version: Jul 15 2022, 14:26:08).

Comment: You should interpret the hex dump as a double. It's not just the `00000000` but also the `3FF00000` which together make a `1`.

Comment: Ok, so 64-bit hexadecimal representation of a floating-point of 3FF0000000000000 i 1. That make sense. Thank you